# verilog n-bit carry lookahead adder problem

Tags: verilog, quartus

I am trying to write a generalized n-bit carry-lookahead adder in verilog/quartus II v13 and losing my mind over getting the final carry-out?

Here is the testbench...

```
`timescale 1ns/1ps
//`define DELAY #10
module cla_adder_4b_tb;
    parameter DATA_WIDTH = 4; //override dats width

    reg [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] a,b;
    reg ci;
    
    wire co;
    wire [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] sum;
    
    cla_adder cla1 (
        .a(a),
        .b(b),
        .cin(ci),
        .sum(sum),
        .cout(co)
        );
    
    initial begin
        a=4'd0;
        b=4'd0;
        ci=0;
    end
        
    initial begin
        #30 
        #10 a=4'd0;
        #10 b=4'd0;
        #10 b=4'd5;
        #10 a=4'd5;
        #10 b=4'd10;
        #10 b=4'd11;
    end

endmodule
```

And here is the cla_adder.v module:

```
module cla_adder(a,b,cin,sum,cout);

parameter DATA_WIDTH = 8;   //8-bit cla adder is the default

    input [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] a;
    input [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] b;
    input cin;
    output [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] sum;
    output cout;
    
    wire [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] gen;      //generate carry
    wire [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] pro;      //propogate carry
    wire [DATA_WIDTH:0] c_tmp;      //data_width carry outs plus one carry in
    
    genvar i,j;
    generate
        assign c_tmp[0] = cin;  // assume c_tmp[0] is driven by cin
        
        //carry generator
        for(j=0;j<DATA_WIDTH;j=j+1)
        begin:carry_side_cla //label
            assign gen[j] = a[j]&b[j];
            assign pro[j] = a[j]^b[j];
            assign c_tmp[j+1] = gen[j]|pro[j]&c_tmp[j];
        end
        
        assign cout = c_tmp[DATA_WIDTH];  //<<<=== This is NOT working
        
        //sum generator
        for(i=0;i<DATA_WIDTH;i=i+1)
        begin:sum_side_cla //label
            assign sum[i] = a[i]^b[i]^c_tmp[i];
        end
    endgenerate
            
endmodule
```

the sum wire is working but cout is always StX??

Answer (score 0):

Icarus Verilog on edaplaygound give a useful warnings:

> warning: Port 1 (a) of cla_adder expects 8 bits, got 4.
> : Padding 4 high bits of the port.
> warning: Port 1 (b) of cla_adder expects 8 bits, got 4.
> : Padding 4 high bits of the port.
> warning: Port 1 (sum) of cla_adder expects 8 bits, got 4.
> : Padding 4 high bits of the port.

Other simulators also gave similar useful warnings.

To resolve the warning and your issue, change `cla_adder cla1` to
`cla_adder #(DATA_WIDTH) cla1` in your test bench.

Comment: the parameter DATA_WIDTH=4 in the test bed overrides the parameter DATA_WIDTH = 8 in the cla_adder module doesn't it? I am just learning verilog.  I used to use vhdl back in school a long time ago.

Comment: Your suggestion fixed it THANKS. I am learning Verilog and I thought putting the parameter for data width was all that was needed.  Now I know I have to add it in the instantiation as well.  GG

Comment: Also I did not see the warnings in the quartus compile.  Test bencch setup is rather baffling to me still in quartus II v13sp0